# WYSIWYG editor vs Hand Code

Tags: html, wysiwyg

What are the pros and cons of using a WYSIWYG editor for web page development vs hand coding?

With the exception of just not knowing how to create something by hand coding is there any reasons to use WYSIWYG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I handcode, but I prefer to work with a wysiwyg editor in tow, and for that reason I'm still using Dreamweaver as an editor.  What I'm doing 95% of the time is handcoding inside the Source editor and viewing the results in the preview.  Occasionally I'll drop into the wysiwyg editor to move blocks around directly though and when I do I find it invaluable.  I *never* use any of Dreamweavers wizards or generated code and I clean up the html manually too.

I see nothing wrong with this approach, it strikes me as the HTML design equivalent of an IDE prompting to complete functions etc. (intellisense or whatever your IDE may call it)

I also always use a templating system of one form or another so my scripting code is totally separate from html.

The combination with Dreamweaver of the occasional wysiwyg edit (invaluable I find when laying things out or making 'macro' layout changes) and the one click preview has kept me with it despite looking at better tools - Aptana, NetBeans etc.  Indeed I would dearly like to move to another system - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377741/need-a-wysiwyg-php-javascript-ide-replacement-for-dreamweaver) - preferably something that runs on Ubuntu and strips out the crud in Dreamweaver leaving just the wysiwyg features and possibly an intelligent Javascript editor, but I'm yet to find anything. [KompoZer](http://kompozer.net/) is starting to look promising though.

Answer (score 4):

WYSIWYG can be handy if you don't know HTML or just want to whip something together extremely fast. You're not going to get clean code, though. Most WSYIWIG editors still throw out a bunch of unneeded dirty HTML instead of clean solid markup.

Anyone familiar with HTML can usually whip up something just as fast by hand in an HTML editor. And it will be clean, xhtml compliant semantic markup instead of thrown together templates with extraneous crud.

If you set up the template and css properly, you can probably be *faster* with hand coding than a WSYIWYG editor, as those work against you when you're trying to create properly abstracted css with degradable semantic markup.

Answer (score 4):

There are a variety of reasons to use a WYSIWYG editor when creating HTML.

- Allows for quick prototyping
- Allows designer-y people to be actively involved in front end development
- Some WYSIWYG tools will set you up with a clean base to be modified (Dreamweaver's CSS layouts are actually pretty good)

I think the important thing to remember is that after you get it into approximate shape, you should dig into the code and make sure there's nothing weird going on.  Nested spans, odd absolute positioning, and (lord almighty) table based layouts count as weird things.  Even if you use a WYSIWYG to start with, you should always check that the code is valid and looks the way you would expect it to.

Comment: IMO The "designery people" should write their own HTML. Not knowing HTML and CSS as a web designer, only tells me that you don't know the medium you're designing for well. HTML and CSS is part of what i call web design - not just photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

If the design isn't terribly important and you're just throwing a website together there's nothing wrong with using a WYSIWYG. Or if you're trying to create a marginally functional mock up for a client it's a good way to get something built quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I develop in ASP.net most of the time, so I'm in VS2008 most of the time; however whenever possible (which is most of the time) I still-hand code....but I do it in VS2008's source mode. When working with ASP.net, theres always somewhat bloated code which you just sort of have to accept (to a point).

However, in my free time, I also do php development, and like hell will I ever ***not*** hand-code with php. Plus, its not like VS with the drag and drop stuff.

Comment: Yeah, the thought of auto generated PHP scares me.

Comment: Right. I love php for small stuff, because it's so lean. But for bigger stuff, thats what asp.net really shines with.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be really good at what you do, as in Guru like good, drop the WYSIWYG stuff and start hand coding. The learning curve is steeper, but it makes you better at what you do in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to maintainability and changeability.  It is usually much easier to change a GUI layout in a GUI editor than by hand.

"Oh you want to move that JTable from this position to this other completely unrelated position".  If you have handcoded it, it basically turns out to be a programming job (which for non-trivial layouts might actually be HARD), but if it is in a good GUI editor, it is probably just a matter of point-click-move-release.

People who handcode probably never have had to do that kind of changes :)

Answer (score 1):

The advantages of using a WYSIWYG editor for web development are pretty obvious. Development is much simpler and faster even if you know how to code web since web development requires to know many different languages and can get messy when trying to get them to work together as planned. Real WYSIWYG designers should be able to solve those complexities by allowing you to visually develop on one form in one layer.
The disadvantages of this kind of development paradigms can be that it sometimes limits you, meaning that you are usually constrained within a predefined framework.

Therefore it is important to find a framework that on top of its WYSIWYG development experience is open to extension and customization. Take a look at http://www.visualwebgui.com/.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same type of thing as Glade versus hand coding your Gtk code.  I think that you add a level of obfuscation and things that might break when you hand edit your code.  However, as Spencer said, if you need to do it and it needs to work; usualy WYSI wil work pretty well and reliably.  If you're doing something that you're going to be keeping up to date and be managing for years to come; you should know every piece of code that is in that application/web page.

Answer (score 0):

Really it comes down to your job function. If you're primarily a designer, WYSIWYG editors can be very handy for creating mock-ups for clients, or prototypes that can be handed to developers to code against.

If you're a developer, you'll probably prefer to hand-code.

Most WYSIWYG editors offer a code view and design view which enables you to switch back and forth pretty easily.

My suggestion is to try and learn how to hand-code your site. After years of web development, I find that hand-coding is faster for me than attempting to use a designer. Moreover, as you gain a better understanding of how HTML and CSS work together you'll find that there's very little that can't be done gracefully.

It can be frustrating to learn, but you'll find that you're better for it in the long run.